# Javascript string searching issue

Tags: javascript, string, search

I'm a self-taught amateur at JS, and thought it's time to finally register here :)

I'm trying (and failing) to write a script that takes a single string out of an array of strings, and checks if it contains certain variable keywords from a drop-down menu. My code: http://jsfiddle.net/apMsc/1/

I think there is some conflict with the drop-down menu and the search/indexOf. My code only seems to work if a keyword is in the beginning of the string. If the keyword is buried deeper, the `search()` returns -1 (I also tried `indexOf`).

For example:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = test3array[0].indexOf(drop1);
```

Where **test3array[0]** is a string `value1@-@ value2@-@ value1@-@ value2`, and **drop1** is a variable from a menu.

The script will work if I search for value1, but not for value2 unless I move it to the beginning. I also tried using `new RegExp(drop1)` based on previous topics here, but it didn't work.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because both `test3array[0]` and `drop1` start with a newline. If you want to get rid of the newlines, call `trim()` on those variables. For example, this works:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
    test3array[0].trim().indexOf(drop1.trim());
```

Edit: Here's some advice for asking questions: You tried to identify the part of your code that doesn't work and posted it here. Finding a minimal testcase before asking a question is a good idea and often even leads you to the solution, but when you do that, you should also check whether your minimal testcase also reproduces the bug. On its own, the line `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = test3array[0].indexOf(drop1);` is correct.

Comment: Fair warning: trim isn't supported by IE8

Comment: That did the trick, thanks :) This was *supposed* to be a simplified example, after I gradually stripped everything else. I guess it could be minimized some more...

Comment: @Alex Regarding what MaxArt said: You might want to use $.trim or so for compatibility with IE8.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, MaxArt. I'll try to fix the source divs to avoid the newlines altogether, but if that won't work it's not going to be a big deal. This is not for professional use :) Ah, the $ could work too :)